# HTML / CSS - Frozen Table Column on the right side

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I've found a solution for fixed/frozen left-column here: http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/

```
    body { font:16px Calibri;}
    table { border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; }
    td {
        margin:0;
        border:3px solid grey; 
        border-top-width:0px; 
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    div { 
        width: 600px; 
        overflow-x:scroll;  
        margin-left:5em; 
        overflow-y:visible;
        padding-bottom:1px;
    }
    .headcol {
        position:absolute; 
        width:5em; 
        left:0;
        top:auto;
        border-right: 0px none black; 
        border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
        margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
    }
    .headcol:before {content: 'Row ';}
    .long { background:yellow; letter-spacing:1em; }​
```

But is it also possible to get a **right** fixed/frozen column without Javascript or another overlaying table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the css like below

```
 div { 
            width: auto; 
            overflow-x:scroll;  
            margin-right:5em; 
            overflow-y:visible;
            padding-bottom:1px; 
        }
        .headcol {
            position:absolute; 
            width:5em; 
            right:0;
            top:auto;
            border-right: 0px none black; 
            border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
            margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
        }
        .headcol:after{content: 'Row ';}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YMvk9/656/)

Comment: Thanks, alot this is working. But i have still a problem with vertical scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/2LPsS/

Comment: How could I use the same to freeze multiple columns?

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for? I made it for one rwo only. You can add as many rows as you want. Check the following HTML and style.

```
<div><table>
        <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    <td class="headcol">1</td></tr>
</table></div>

​

        body { font:16px Calibri;}
        table { border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; }
        td {
            margin:0;
            border:3px solid grey; 
            border-top-width:0px; 
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
        div { 
            width: 600px; 
            overflow-x:scroll; 
            overflow-y:visible;
            padding-bottom:1px;
        }
        .headcol {
            position:absolute; 
            width:5em; 
            right:0;
            top:auto;
            border-right: 0px none black; 
            border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
            margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
        }
        .headcol:before {content: 'Row ';}
        .long { background:yellow; letter-spacing:1em; }​
```